# Ansible, how to copy host key from control machine to targets

Tags: authentication, ssh, configuration, cloud, ansible

How to copy the ansible control machine *host key* to the target server *known_hosts*? The problem is, ansible expect this setup have been already made, to connect to those target servers without prompt.

Should I use tasks with password authentication and secret variables to setup the keys, or configure host keys manually before provisioning?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass` variables, or pass them from command line when you run the playbook:
--user and --ask-pass.

You can put variables to var file encoded with Ansible Vault to keep them secret(but don't forget to include this file for you target hosts)

Please check this answer for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/628989/how-set-to-ansible-a-default-user-pass-pair-to-ssh-connection

You can specify the variable for SSH key called `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` later in the task(I suppose you should use `set_fact`). I'm not completely sure but if you play around perhaps it would work.

P.S. in other hand, if you already specify the username and password, there is no difference what to use

Comment: How can I define the first task to use password, and subsequent tasks use ssh key in the same playbook? Group or host variables won't do, as they will affect all the tasks. Is it possible to overwrite these parameters for a single task, and get the password from a var file?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen I updated the answer. Sorry if it don't full, it is my guessing on the problem